# Using partitionBy on a DataFrameWriter writes directory layout with column names not just values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, configuration, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.0.

I have a DataFrame. My code looks something like the following:

```
df.write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").format("csv").option("header", "true").save(s"s3://bucket/")
```

And when the program executes, it writes files in the following format:

```
s3://bucket/year=2016/month=11/day=15/file.csv
```

How do I configure the format to be like this:

```
s3://bucket/2016/11/15/file.csv
```

I would also like to know if it is possible to configure the filename.

Here is the relevant documentation that seems pretty sparse...
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter

```
partitionBy(colNames: String*): DataFrameWriter[T]
Partitions the output by the given columns on the file system. If specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to Hive's partitioning scheme. As an example, when we partition a dataset by year and then month, the directory layout would look like:

year=2016/month=01/
year=2016/month=02/
Partitioning is one of the most widely used techniques to optimize physical data layout. It provides a coarse-grained index for skipping unnecessary data reads when queries have predicates on the partitioned columns. In order for partitioning to work well, the number of distinct values in each column should typically be less than tens of thousands.

This was initially applicable for Parquet but in 1.5+ covers JSON, text, ORC and avro as well.
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this? other then renaming ..

Comment: Unfortunately no; I told our business owner this was a technology limitation and we moved forward with the file structure named with the 'year=' and 'month='.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected and desired behavior. Spark uses directory structure for partition discovery and pruning and the correct structure, including column names, is necessary for it to work.

You also have to remember that partitioning drops the columns used for partitioning.

If you need specific directory structure you should use downstream process to rename directories.

Comment: this just makes it hard to deal with downstream as s3's Boto lib hates "=" chars in the bucket name :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following script to relayout the directories's name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Rename repartition folder: delete COLUMN=, e.g. DATE=20170708 to 20170708.

path=$1
col=$2
for f in `hdfs dfs -ls $ | awk '{print $NF}' | grep $col=`; do
    a="$(echo $f | sed s/$col=//)"
    hdfs dfs -mv "$f" "$a"
done
```